# Tooltip stays visible for radio buttons in btn-group-toggle after clicking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a `btn-group-toggle` to show toggle-able buttons with tooltips on top of them. This works, but the tooltip doesn't disappear when the mouse is moved away after clicking.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-secondary active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 1">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>#1
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 2">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">#2
        </label>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3, Popper 1.14.3, and JQuery 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this JS:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="toggle">

  <label class="btn btn-secondary active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 1">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>#1
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 2">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">#2
        </label>
</div>
```

Basically, it directly hides the tooltip upon clicking.